# Selecting row via PrimeFaces' jQuery dataTable.selectRow(index) fails with: a is undefined

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I have the following simple PrimeFaces datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="list"
             value="#{collisionManager.nodeCollisions}"
             var="cln"
             selection="#{collisionManager.selectedCollisionsArray}"
             rowKey="#{cln.id}"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" process="@this" update="@this" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" process="@this" update="@this" />

    <p:ajax event="rowToggle" global="false" />

    <p:column styleClass="row-toggler">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />

    ...

    <p:rowExpansion>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            ... some info about the row
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:rowExpansion>

</p:dataTable>
```

As you can see there's a `<p:rowToggler>` column and a multi-select checkbox `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" />` column in the table. Here's a picture:

[image]

The PF implementation of the checkbox selection however seems to update the whole table after clicking a checkbox, which causes all currently expanded row expansions to be collapsed again.

To remedy this (and to make the unselect all checkbox work due to "CantReplicate" bug http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3794), we decided to implement the multi-select boxes ourselves.

```
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
```

then became:

```
    <p:column>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{collisionManager.checkedStates[rowIndex]}">
            <p:ajax process="@this"
                    update="@this"
                    listener="#{collisionManager.processCheck}" />
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:column>
```

This basically works as intended (via a list of boolean "checked" states in the bean). However the currently selected rows aren't highlighted.

When updating the whole datatable after a check action via

```
            <p:ajax ...
                    update=":collision-form:list"
                    ... >
```

the respective rows are correctly highlighted according to the boolean state when additionally putting

```
<p:dataTable id="list"
             ...
             rowStyleClass="#{collisionManager.checkedStates[rowIndex] ? 'ui-state-highlight' : ''}">
```

on the datatable, but the effect of all currently expanded row expansions being collapsed after a check action persists. So, to work around the rows being collapsed (due to the inability of a row toggler to set an initial expanded/collapsed state), updating the whole list doesn't seem to be the way to go.

I then had the idea to patch the highlight onto the row by using jQuery. I added a simple call to `oncomplete="collisionTable.selectRow(#{rowIndex});"`:

```
<p:column>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{collisionManager.checkedStates[rowIndex]}">
        <p:ajax process="@this"
                update="@this"
                listener="#{collisionManager.processCheck}"
                oncomplete="collisionTable.selectRow(#{rowIndex});" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:column>
```

This basically highlights the respective row, but somewhere after the DOM is updated the call to `collisionTable.selectRow(#{rowIndex});` fails with some JS error:

a is undefined

**Firebug says:**

"Resuming debugger: error during debugging loop: TypeError: firstViewRangeElement is null"

a is undefined

Line 1

**FF error console says:**

TypeError: a is undefined

htps://localhost:8181/blablabla/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces

Line: 1

PrimeFaces={escapeClientId:function(a){return"#"+a.replace(/:/g,"\:")},....... **[veeery long minimized code line]**

This error causes the JS/AJAX engine to stop, so anything beyond the first check action hangs up the whole UI.

**Q**:

Why does this very simple select call fail?
What's going wrong?

**Q2**:

How do you debug this?

Edit: I also tried the oncomplete to call a function in a separate JS file. This allows me to set a breakpoint in Firebug, but it doesn't get me any further. The only things I realize when stepping through are that the previous state and not the one after the check action is passed to that method and that the whole selectRow fails *after* the highlight is processed. Current code:

```
oncomplete="processChecked( #{collisionManager.checkedStates[rowIndex]}, #{rowIndex} );"
```

The select-row.js file:

```
function processChecked( checkedState, rowIndex )
{
    alert( "Checked state = " + checkedState + ", index = " + rowIndex );

    if ( !checkedState )
    {
        collisionTable.selectRow( rowIndex, true );
    }
    else
    {
        collisionTable.unselectRow( rowIndex, true );
    }
}
```

Note, that the condition is reversed. If anyone knows why the old state is passed, please enlighten me.

Comment: The @this tag in the ajax events refer to the table, not a specific checkbox. This is why the entire table is updated. I'm not sure why you even have those events in the first place though, they are not needed for selection to work. Why do you want/need them?

Comment: I don't think that is true. When setting the `update="@this"` to `@none` the row selection highlight isn't set. `update="@this"` and update="@none" do the same BTW: no highlight on the current row according to `rowStyleClass="#{collisionManager.checkedStates[rowIndex] ? 'ui-state-highlight' : ''}"`. I must update the datatable because of this and to implement select all/unselect all because PF has a bugged unselect, too: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3794

Comment: There's no need to use rowStyleClass. Selected rows will automatically have the ui-state-highlight class applied when the checkboxes are clicked. It really doesn't seem like custom selection handling is what you're looking for. If you remove the ajax event for the toggleSelect event using unselect all should be working fine.

Comment: You should realize that the "select all" checkbox is not persisted as a property on the datatable, it's mostly clientside. I can agree that it's a bug that the "select all" checkbox is not checked if all rows are selected from the start when the table is rendered, but this shouldn't really cause you any issues.

Comment: The main problem was/is that any rowTogglers are **collapsed** when using the standard PF procedure to handle multi-selects. PF seems to update the whole table, so this can't be avoided. The row toggler has no attribute `expanded="..."`, so the manual checkboxes seemed the only way to go. This is why I tried to highlight the clicked checkboxes' row via the jQuery "hack" above (at least that was the idea) without updating the whole table.

Comment: The rowStyleClass is indeed not needed in general. As explained, you only need this to show that when using per row whole list updates (which don't apply anymore because they also cause the row togglers to collapse).

Comment: The only reason that the rowTogglers are collapsed is your <p:ajax update="@this"> tags. This causes the entire datatable to be refreshed, and the expanded state of rowexpansions isn't persisted so it is lost. If you remove all of your ajax events it should work fine.

Comment: hello, i have some doubt like this:
how identifying in js that the selected line is already selected?